# How does a has_many :through association and its join model attribute interact?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, nested-form-for

I am having real difficulty getting my head around the issue of setting the attribute in my join model?

My models:

```
  class Contract < AR::Base 
    has_many :codelines
    has_many :codes, :through => :codelines

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :codes

    attr_accessible :codes_attributes, :codes; :authnum, :st_date, :end_date
  end

  class Codeline < AR::Base
    belongs_to :contract
    belongs_to :code
    units_alloc ...... this is the attribute I would like to set
  end

  class Code < AR::Base
    has_many :codelines
    has_many :contracts, :through => :codelines
  end
```

The new action of my app/controllers/contracts_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @contract = Contract.new
    @contract.codes.build
  end
```

the partial for my view in app/views/contracts/_fields.html.haml

```
  <fieldset><legend>Enter Billing Code Details</legend>
  = f.fields_for :codes do |ff|
     .field
        = ff.label :name, "Code Name"
        %br/
        = ff.text_field :code_name
     .field
     .
     .
   = f.fields_for :codelines do |ff|
     .field
       = ff.label :name, "Units Alloc"
       %br/
       = ff.text_field :units_alloc, :precision => 6, :scale => 2, :size => 10
  </fieldset>
```

From reading Rails Guides and watching railscasts #196 and #197 and researching nested attributes on the internet I came to the understanding that the **@contract.codes.build** line in the new action of my app/controllers/contracts_controller.rb not only built the code object but that it also built the codelines object. If I leave my new action of my app/controllers/contracts_controller.rb as above that is exactly what happens. My codelines table is populated as follows:

```
    id       contract_id       code_id       units_alloc
     1             1                1                  .... @contract.codes.build
```

But if you look at my view I would actually like to set units_alloc and this line **@contract.codes.build** does not give me access to units_alloc since it is in the codeline model. I added **@contract.codelines.build** to the new action of my app/controllers/contracts_controller.rb and now the units_alloc shows in my view and I am able to set it. But now I have two rows in my codelines table. One resulting from the **@contract.codes.build** where both the code object and codeline object are built and the second row is as a result of the **@contract.codelines.build** and my codelines table is as follows:

```
    id       contract_id       code_id       units_alloc
     1             1                1                  .... @contract.codes.build
     2             1                             80.00 .... @contract.codelines.build
```

Should'nt I be able to get access to units_alloc through the first build given by @contract.codes.build, where both the code object and the codeline object is built?

Does anyone know if my understanding of this issue is correct or could you point me to a resource where all will be revealed?

Just as an after thought I built the code object through codelines and I got the same result.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Update**
I can get my codelines table to have only one record with all the associated id's set as follows:

My console:

```
    @contract = Contract.new(authnum: "900700", st_date: "2012-01-01",  end_date:
    "2012-30-06")

    @contract.save

    @code = Code.new(code_name: "S-5463", status: "Active",   description: 
    "This and That")

    @code.save

    @codeline = @code.codelines.build(:units_alloc => "80.00",  :contract => @contract)

    @codeline.save

    @codeline
    => #<Codeline id: 91, contract_id: 64, code_id: 54, units_alloc: 80.00>
```

Using pgadmin3 I check my codelines table and I get just one record, namely:

```
    id    contract_id    code_id   units_alloc
    91         64            54       80.00
```

Now the test is to get my contracts_controller new/create action to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution at this site, [debugging nested_forms](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1346-debug-nested-forms).

It is the ninth bullet down where you read that if you are working with a has_many :through association then you need to base your nested_form on the join model or something close to that.

I quickly ran a test by refactoring some code here and there and I now have a workable nested form that serves up the correct params to the controller which in turns processes it correctly and my codelines table now has just one record.

Answer (score 0):

For the new,

An existing Contract with an existing code.  Bind them together.

Create a codeline using those two ids and the units_alloc

```
codeline.contract = contract
codeline.code = code
codeline.units_alloc = 1

codeline.save
```

When you want to show

use `Codeline.all`

---

When you have a new list of objects that you want to create on the fly, like Array.new

```
post.comments.build
```

to build a new array of empty comments for my post instead of it being nil

I hope this helps.  I am new to rails myself.

Edit

First time visiting the page the app will try to create  a new codeline until it is saved

```
@codeline = Codeline.new
@codeline.contract = Contract.new #or find it from the table, depends on the logic
@codeline.code = Code.new
@codeline.units_alloc = 0 #default value
```

Comment: Thanks @D3mon-1stVFW, do I put the codeline.contract = contract in my create action of my contracts_controller. Also is the codeline.units_alloc = 1 a boolean?

Comment: The way I look at it is, when they create a codeline, they are picking from an existing contract & code.  Otherwise, based on the logic they either can be created on the fly or they can be found from the table.  The controller for that page is where they will go based on the paths.  I see it going in the codeline_controller.  The units alloc is just a number, not a boolean.

Comment: Thanks again ... I have to run now but I will play with this tomorrow and then mark your response as an answer ... great to meet someone else who is new to  rails ... albeit more advanced than I:)

Comment: my pleasure, I will check this post if someone has a better answer than I.  If I have free time I will create a simple app with the same idea to see where I get.  good luck.

Comment: I tried your solution out, but it did not work for me:}, thanks anyway. My problem is the nested_attributes, I am building new clients, codes and units_alloc associated with those codes on the contracts form and as shown in the original posting it works but I have some concern about the fact that I have two rows in my codelines table, where I thought I should only have one that encapsulates the build for both codes and units_alloc.